# Is there a way to “derive” a (non-exact) functor which preserves images?

Tags: ct.category-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-categories

Let $F : \mathcal A \to \mathcal B$ be an additive functor between abelian categories. If $F$ is left exact, then under certain conditions $F$ admits right derived functors which “measure” its failure to be exact. If $F$ is right exact, then dually $F$ can often be derived.

Being left or right exact are ways to ber “almost exact, but not quite”. Another way to be “almost exact, but not quite” is to preserve both epimorphisms and monomorphisms — or equivalently, to preserve images. I’m tempted to call such a functor “outer exact”. For example, for fixed $n \in \mathbb Z$, the functor $Ab \to Ab, X \to nX$, which sends $X$ to the image of the map $n : X \to X$, is a functor which preserves images.

**Question:** Let $F : \mathcal A \to \mathcal B$ be an additive functor between  nice abelian categories, and assume that $F$ preserves images. Then is there some collection of functors $I_n F : \mathcal A \to \mathcal B$ which “measure” the failure of $F$ to be exact in some sense?

This is of course a vague question, and probably most of the difficulty lies in trying to make the question more precise.

**Motivation:**

Let $\mathcal A$ be an abelian category, and let $\mathcal A^{[1]}$ be the category of morphisms in $\mathcal A$. Then I can think of three canonical functors $\mathcal A^{[1]} \to \mathcal A$: one can take the kernel, the cokernel, or the image. I know how to measure the failure of exactness of the first two, but not the third. There’s at least one context where these three functors sit in a kind of “triality” — if $\mathcal A$ is the Freyd envelope of a triangulated category, then images, kernels, and cokernels can be understood in terms of one another by rotating triangles. This leads me to hope that whatever I can do with kernels and cokernels, I can also do with images.

Comment: Usual derived functors do the job just as well, in my opinion; you just do not have that zeroth derived functor is isomorphic to the original one. Do you have any reason to use something else?

Comment: @DenisT What form of "usual derived functor" applies to a functor which is neither left nor right exact?

Comment: Suppose you have an additive functor $F: A \to B$ between abelian categories, and derived categories of $A$ and $B$ exist. Let $q_A$ and $q_B$ be the quotient functors from homotopy categories of complexes to the derived categories of $A$ and $B$. Left/right derived functor (if it exists) is a left/right Kan extension of [pointwise application of $F$ on homotopy categories composed with $q_B$] along $q_A$. Exactness properties of the initial functor really do not matter for the existence, it depends on whether acyclic complexes in $A$ form a (co)localizing subcategory.

Comment: According to whether you want your derived functor to be defined on the bounded, bounded above/below, or the whole unbounded derived category of $A$, you'll have to put more and more niceness properties on $A$; but besides additivity, $F$ can be anything.